# $(window).width() and $('body').scrollLeft() not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-body

Sample: http://kat.isltest.net/col/

This sample site is working in chrome. The function is the body is centered even it contains a wide div of 1600px. The scrollbar is then by default centered in every window size.

Now, the problem is this is not working in IE and Firefox.

Here's the code:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 1600) {
    $('body').scrollLeft(0);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1400) {
    $('body').scrollLeft(110);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1360) {
    $('body').scrollLeft(130);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1280) {
    $('body').scrollLeft(170);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1152) {
    $('body').scrollLeft(235);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
    $('body').scrollLeft(300);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 800){
    $('body').scrollLeft(400);
}
```

DO you guys have idea why?
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Please include the code relevant to problem in the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, done! check it again, thanks!

Comment: May I ask why do you want this behaviour? It doesn't make any sense to me. If you want a visitor to always see the important parts of a website, no matter what window size, I would consider a responsive webdesign.

Comment: @MarioA that's what I'm thinking also. but the client wants to.

Comment: @kgam Maybe you should have a serios talk with your customer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap you code with a listener that executes when the window is resized, otherwise the scrollbars are adjusted only once:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  /* your code */
});
```

I guess the reason that chrome adjusts it's vertical scrollbar to the center when the width of the browser window is smaller then 1600px is default behaviour and has nothing to do with your code.

**Edit**

Further, you need to use `$(document).scrollLeft()` instead of `$('body').scrollLeft()` if you want the viewport to scroll.

Comment: I've tried to wrap it on $(window).on('resize', function() { } but still not fixed.  (http://kat.isltest.net/col/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do scroll on click any button then you can do following using jquery.

```
$('#next').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('.surr-cor').animate({
scrollLeft: "+=1350px"
}, "slow");
});
```

Mention event for firefox because it works on events. You can replace `.surr-cor` to your div element or `body`